# Alternative to trumped

Tags: single-word-requests

Personally, the word [trump/trumped](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/trump) is overshadowed by ugly American politics and I would prefer not to write/speak it unless absolutely necessary.

I see the comments saying that no one would associate the two meanings within a given context and that it is pointless to try and substitute a word that has been used for a long time, but **I just don't want to use it.** It has too much meaning for me and I do not want to write it down.

Consider the following sentence:

> Miguel's hand revealed that he had indeed trumped Jack's queen of spades.

**What would a good alternative to *trumped* be?**

I have looked at and ruled out all the following potential synonyms:

- **[outclass](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/outclass)**

Definition:

> to surpass in excellence or quality, especially by a wide margin; be superior

Reasoning:

Cards aren't superior to each other.

- **[upstage](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/upstage)**

Definition:

> to draw attention away from.

Reasoning:

The cards aren't drawing attention away from each other.

- **[eclipse](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/eclipse)**

Definition:

> If one thing is eclipsed by a second thing that is bigger, newer, or more important than it, the first thing is no longer noticed because the second thing gets all the attention.

Reasoning:

The cards aren't drawing attention away from each other.

- **[surpass](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/surpass)**

Definition:

> to become better, greater, or stronger than.

Reasoning:

The cards aren't better, greater, or stronger than each other.

- **[outdo](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/outdo)**

Definition:

> to surpass in execution or performance.

Reasoning:

Cards can not surpass each other, nor can they surpass in execution or performance.

- **[outperform](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/outperform)**

Definition:

> to do well in a particular job or activity compared to others of a similar type.

Reasoning:

Cards can do well in a job or activity because they don't have any. They are only objects.

**So what word should I use instead of *trumped*?**

Comment: Using any other word here would involve a non-standard usage. The answer is not to let personal non-preferences (or rather what is seen as an undesirable association) win over good established usages / conventions.

Comment: You can’t change that particular usage instance because it is refering to the card game directly. Where you *can* change it is where you’re using it metaphorically in a different context.

Comment: Card games have been around for a lot longer than the previous US president, and will be around long after he is gone, and native speakers will assume the traditional meaning.

Comment: I once read an account of a 19th century English explorer, lost in an African jungle, who thought he was doomed, but he saw the light of a fire and heard faint voices. He went towards it, and, as he grew closer, he heard a voice ring out - "You f*****g bastard, you've trumped my ace!". He wrote later: "It was at that moment that I knew I was in the company of Christians and gentlemen".

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Is this why Seven No-Trump outbids everybody? :)

Comment: The association of a word with a controversial political figure is not a good reason for altering the rules of a game.  But it would not be difficult.

Comment: In cards, *trump* does not usually refer to any and every winning card or hand, it refers specifically to cards of whichever suit has been designated *trumps* for the current hand. It doesn't make sense to try to replace this standard game terminology in the context of actual card games.

Comment: Almost anything is a good alternative to *trumped*. We've already had too much of that.

Comment: I just thought of two probably superfluous things to add. The word 'trump' can also mean a note blown on a trumpet, and in the Christian tradition, the end of the world will be initiated by the 'Last Trump', when an angel blows upon a celestial trumpet created for the purpose. There is a HG Wells short story in which the instrument is accidentally dropped and falls to earth; it is found and no-one can make it produce a sound. It is taken to a workshop and connected to an air machine, with calamitous results.

Comment: The other thing is the fact that in North West England, 'trump' (noun and verb) means 'fart', probably by analogy with the musical meaning.

Comment: If you're going to refuse to use the word everyone knows and understands, you should just make up a word instead of confusing everyone by trying to repurpose a word that has a meaning that is different from "trump". That way people know you're intentionally abusing the language and not making a mistake. Who knows, you might invent something that will catch on. I tried changing "renege" among our Euchre group because saying "you filthy reneger!" is very socially unacceptable in my accent, but everyone else thought I could just grow up and stop calling people names. *shrug*

Comment: @ColleenV Interesting idea. While I am at it, I will walk around with a sign saying "I'm intentionally abusing the English language."

Comment: One of the best bits about the English language is how wonderfully creative you can be when abusing it and still be understood :)

Comment: In the game of bridge, there is no other term except beaten. And it was around long before the arse. In bridge, if the trumps are diamonds, spades trump or beat diamonds. You picked the only context where metaphors ain't gonna cut it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a gaming context (especially poker and other card games, as you seem to be implying), I would recommend **outrank**. Cards and hands have ranks and typically the winning card is based on the relative rankings.

From [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/outrank):

> Outrank
> transitive verb
> 1: to rank higher than
> 2: to exceed in importance

However, in the context of bridge (if that is what you are talking about), you don't really have any good options. The trump suit has that name and you can't really change it anymore than you can rename the king in chess.

Answer (score 5):

[Etymologically](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=trump), the word *trump* in card games was derived from the word *triumph*, which was used for the same purpose before *trump*. So you could just use four-century old lingo, and say *triumph*.

Semantically, it makes as much sense as any of your other suggestions, and it sounds similar, so it will be easier to remember.

Comment: Why use this 16th century Italian game, 'trionfi', as the basis a new name for the phenomenon?  I should, personally, be unable to mutter at my partner "triumphs are diamonds, you idiot", without thinking of the word 'trump' together with controversial owner of that name.  It would make me feel foolish as well as uncomfortable.  It will surely go on being 'trumps' when our Donald, love him or hate him, is out of the picture entirely.  Any word will do, even one meaning nothing.  If you must, try "My ace was 'downed' by a 'downer'? It isn't pretty, but it does what it says.

Comment: Miguel's hand revealed that he had indeed triumphed over [??] Jack's queen of spades. The trick to the context in the question is the game of bridge. Ergo, all these lists of suggestions hit that brick wall.

Answer (score 0):

*beat*

> defeat (someone) in a game or other competitive situation. "she
> beat him easily at chess"

is simple and accurate and can be used regarding a card game or any other context that trump would be used.

Comment: Actually, for bridge this is right: Miguel's hand revealed that he had indeed beaten Jack's queen of spades. You do not deserve two downvotes. It annoys me so much when the clueless downvote the clued in. :) In fact, this is the only other term that would work in the game of bridge. Bravo.

Comment: @Lambie A standard rule in these kinds of card games is that you must follow suit, otherwise you lose. The exception is that a trump beats **any** card other than a higher-ranked trump (including joker). "Miguel's card beat Jack's queen of spades" gives no clue as to whether Miguel's card was (say) a king of spades or (say) a three of trumps. "Trumping" a card is a *very specific and defined subset* of "beating" a card, and therefore the generic "beat" cannot replace the specific use of "trump".

Comment: @ChappoHasn'tForgottenMonica I actually do play bridge. In Bridge, if the hand is a no-trump hand, the highest card in any suit wins. If, on the other hand, there is a suit being played, the highest card in that suit wins the round. So, it is not "these kinds of cards games", it is Bridge.

Comment: @Lambie at no point in either the question or the above answer is the card game identified as *bridge*, and there are plenty of other games in which a suit can be nominated as trumps. Your emphasis on one particular card game, and one specific scenario within that game, is misplaced.